# Cypher query slow when intermediate node labels are specified

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query

```
MATCH (p1:`Article` {article_id:'1234'})--(a1:`Author` {name:'Jones, P'})
MATCH (p2:`Article` {article_id:'5678'})--(a2:`Author` {name:'Jones, P'})
MATCH (p1)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(c1:`Author`)-[h1:HAS_NAME]->(l1)
MATCH (p2)-[:WRITTEN_BY]->(c2:`Author`)-[h2:HAS_NAME]->(l2)
WHERE l1=l2 AND c1<>a1 AND c2<>a2
RETURN c1.FullName, c2.FullName, h1.distance + h2.distance
```

On my local Neo4j server, running this query takes ~4 seconds and `PROFILE` shows >3 million db hits. If I don't specify the `Author` label on `c1` and `c2` (it's redundant thanks to the relationship labels), the same query returns the same output in 33ms, and `PROFILE` shows <200 db hits.

When I run the same two queries on a larger version of the same database that's hosted on a remote server, this difference in performance vanishes.

Both dbs have the same constraints and indexes. Any ideas what else might be going wrong?

Comment: "difference in performance vanishes." - On the larger data set, how many db hits and how much time do the queries require? A remark: if `l1` and `l2` are the same, you could simply use the same variable for them.

Comment: 290 db hits when the `Author` node label is specified and 265 when it's not. It takes around 150ms in either case.

Comment: Oh, and using `l1` in place of `l2` results in ~2000 db hits and slightly slower results (~190ms).

Comment: where do the 3 million DB hits occur? can you post a picture of the profiled plan with steps expanded? different data can blow things up even when the schema is the same.

Comment: I also have many questions: 1. Do you really need to store an author's name in 2 different ways (using the `name` property of the `Author` node, and also in a name node)? 2. Does a distinct name have a unique name node? 3. Is it possible for multiple `Author` nodes to have the same `name` property value? 4. What indexes/constraints have you created for `Article(article_id)` and/or `Author(name)`?

Comment: @ToreEschliman: Here you go! http://imgur.com/a/WyiTf

Comment: @cybersam 1, 2 and 3: Authors' names are not unique, but the `Name` nodes are. So multiple `Author` nodes (who share a name) are connected to the same `Name` node. This makes finding other authors with the same name a graph traversal rather than a lookup, and saves us from having quadratically many pairwise relationships. 4. `Article(article_id)` is unique, and we have a separate unique ID for authors (the concatenation of their name and the article_id). So `Author(name)` is not unique.

Answer (score 2):

Your query has a lot of unnecessary stuff in it, so first off, here's a cleaner version of it that is less likely to get misinterpreted by the planner:

```
MATCH (name:Name) WHERE NOT name.name = 'Jones, P'
WITH name
MATCH (:`Article` {article_id:'1234'})-[:WRITTEN_BY]->()-[h1:HAS_NAME]->(name)<-[h2:HAS_NAME]-()<-[:WRITTEN_BY]-(:`Article` {article_id:'5678'})
RETURN name.name, h1.distance + h2.distance
```

There's really only one path you want to find, and you want to find it for any author whose name is not `Jones, P`. Take advantage of your shared `:Name` nodes to start your query with the smallest set of definite points and expand paths from there. You are generating a massive cartesian product by stacking all those `MATCH` statements and then filtering them out.

As for the difference in query performance, it appears that the query planner is trying to use the `Author` label to build your 3rd and 4th paths, whereas if you leave it out, the planner will only touch the much narrower set of `:Article`s (fixed by indexed property), then expand relationships through the (incidentally very small) set of nodes that have `-[:WRITTEN_BY]->` relationships, and then the (also incidentally very small) set of those nodes that have a `-[:HAS_NAME]->` relationship. That decision is based partly on the predictable size of the various sets, so if you have a different number of `:Author` nodes on the server, the planner will make a smarter choice and not use them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query formulated your way takes over a second and uses >1 million db hits on my local instance, but is almost identically fast on the server. I actually started with a query more like yours expecting a single pattern to be faster, and it was only in trying to speed up the query that I discovered that breaking it up into separate `MATCH` clauses resulted in 50x improvement. But I now think this might be due to a corruption in the db: `MATCH (a:Author) RETURN COUNT(a)` returns 0, but `MATCH (a:Author) RETURN a LIMIT 10` happily returns ten examples of `Author` nodes.

Comment: ah, that `COUNT` info is an essential part of the query planning, so it's going to result in bad choices all around if it's corrupted.

Comment: your instinct was correct, though, the single pattern will almost always be faster if your database isn't corrupted.

Comment: Great - glad to have gotten to the bottom of it! Thanks again!